# Payment confirmation php+android

Tags: php, web-services

I am converting `PYTHON` web service to `PHP`. after user select his orders from the app, browser run, and open payment page. after payment done I want to back to the app again ...

`PYTHON` after payment done.(status 100) :

```
    if result.Status == 100:
        response = HttpResponse("", status=302)
        response['Location'] = "url://siteurl.com/?type=profile"
        return response
```

`PHP` converted code :

```
    if ($result->Status == 100) {
        $response['Status'] = true;
        $response['Message'] = "ok";
        $response['Location'] = "url://siteurl.com/?type=profile";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Problem is: App doesn't run again... (Python code run app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the php version you have to set the appropriate headers.
`302` means it's a temporary redirect. So :

```
if ($result->Status == 100) {
    header('Location: url://siteurl.com/?type=profile', true, 302);
    exit('');
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
I have "complete action using" page on the response. How can I start my app without this page?

Comment: @PardisAk Please explain more. I don't understand what you're meaning by saying you have a "complete action using" page on the response.

Comment: Irani hastin ? :D

Comment: bale :)))
khob in linki ke mikhad baz beshe to gushi, hamin linki has ke inja neveshti? yani `http://siteurl.com/?type=profile`

Comment: bebinid man ye proje e hast daram az python be php avazesh mikonam chon sherkat az pas hazine ha barnemiad va inke tose dahande ham bara kame. az dargahe zarin pal estefade mikonan bad hame chi dorost anjam mishe vaghti mikham az dargah biad to app dobare in link ro baz mikardan va nemidonam toie app che etefaqi miofte , alan on headeri ke goftid set kardam dorost anjam mishe faqat do ta moshkel dare yeki inke moghe bargasht be jaie inke mostaghim biad to app safhe entekhab baz mishe ke dar kenar app ma google chrom and browsere goshi hast

Comment: aghe mororgar baz konam in link baz mishe aghe app entekhab konam miad to app va dorost mishe hame chi alan mikham in safhe entekhab mororgara baz nashe va mostaghim bere to app migan ba pythono injori bode

Comment: tu in kodi ke man dadam beja `http` bezar `url` bebin doros mishe?

Comment: bale daqiqan moshkelesh hami bod :))

Comment: @PardisAk khahesh mikonam :) movafagh bashi